# Can I train an ELMo model from scratch using allennlp.modules.elmo.Elmo?

Tags: python, machine-learning, deep-learning, allennlp, elmo

I've been looking to train my own ELMo model for the past week and came across these two implementations [allenai/bilm-tf](https://github.com/allenai/bilm-tf) & [allenai/allennlp](https://github.com/allenai/allennlp). I've been facing a few roadblocks for a few techniques I've tried and would like to clarify my findings, so that I can get a clearer direction.

As my project revolves around healthcare, I would like to train the embeddings from scratch for better results. The dataset I am working on is MIMIC-III and the entire dataset is stored in one .csv, unlike 1 Billion Word Language Model Benchmark (data used in tutorials) where files are stored in separate .txt files.

I was following this "Using ELMo as a PyTorch Module to train a new model" [tutorial](https://github.com/allenai/allennlp/blob/v0.8.3/tutorials/how_to/elmo.md#using-elmo-as-a-pytorch-module-to-train-a-new-model) but I figured out that one of the requirements is a .hdf5 weights_file.

**(Question)** Does this mean that I will have to train a bilm model first to get .hdf5 weights to input? Can I train an ELMo model from scratch using allennlp.modules.elmo.Elmo? Is there any other way where I can train a model this way with an empty .hdf5 as I was able to run this successfully with tutorial data.

**(Question)** What will be the best method for me to train my embeddings? (PS: some methods I've tried are documented below). In my case where I will probably need a custom DatasetReader, rather than converting the csv to txt files, wasting memory.

---

Here, let me go into the details of other methods I have tried so far. Serves as a backstory to the main question of what may be the best technique. Please let me know if you know of any other methods to train my own ELMo model, or if one of the following methods are preferred over the others.

I've tried training a model using the `allennlp train ...` command by following [this tutorial](https://towardsdatascience.com/pytorch-elmo-844d2391a0b2#b484). However, I was unable to run with tutorial data due to the following error which I am still unable to solve.

```
allennlp.common.checks.ConfigurationError: Experiment specified GPU device 1 but there are only 1 devices  available.
```

Secondly, this is a technique that I found but have not tried. Similar to the technique above it uses the `allennlp train ...` command but instead I use [allenai/allennlp-template-config-files](https://github.com/allenai/allennlp-template-config-files) as a template and modify the Model and DatasetReader.

Lastly, I tried using the TensorFlow implementation [allenai/bilm-tf](https://github.com/allenai/bilm-tf) following tutorials like [this](https://appliedmachinelearning.blog/2019/11/30/training-elmo-from-scratch-on-custom-data-set-for-generating-embeddings-tensorflow/). However, I would like to avoid this method as TF1 is quite outdated. Besides receiving tons of warnings, I faced an error for CUDA as well.

```
2021-09-14 17:31:36.222624: E tensorflow/stream_executor/cuda/cuda_driver.cc:936] failed to allocate 18.45M (19346432 bytes) from device: CUDA_ERROR_OUT_OF_MEMORY
```

Comment: Hi @Goh Jia Yi, were you able to train your own ELMo word embeddings? If so, could you share your methodology?